# Clickable Table of Contents in Pentaho Report Designer

Tags: html, report

I am able to produce a paginated HTML output report. I am creating a table of contents where I would like my users to be able to click the field name and it brings them to that page in the HTML paginated report.

The issue that I am running into is Pentaho Report Designer seems to want to drilldown to a different URL. The functionality that I am looking for is the table of contents should stay within the report and not require an outside URL.

Does anyone know if there is a clickable table of contents in Pentaho Report Designer that references its own results?

If I am able to do this, I plan to also make a return to home button. I can and have referenced Excel Sheets if the output is Excel with multiple sheets but my output for this report is HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to make a clickable table of contents. What I ended up doing is making a subreport that contained the table of contents and had it appear on every page with reference to what page the content fell on. You can do this via a group inside of a group. In, the nested group put the subreport in the group footer (this is if you have page breaks on a group).

Best of luck out there. If you really want to dive into Pentaho Report Designer, check out the sticky feature in the page header/footer, group header/footer, and details header/footer report elements.